# How to get the date of latest installed android version?

Tags: android, date, time

I want to get the date and time (isn't that important) when the user installed his latest android version on the smartphone.
I searched in google and looked after in the Android Reference, but didn'f find anything like that.

My first thought was the class `android.os.BUILD` but there is nothing.

`android.od.BUILD.Time` is just the date when the Build was compiled.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't exist. You might be able to derive a date based on the created timestamp of some system files, but that's probably not very reliable. Explain what you need it for, and maybe someone can suggest an alternate way of solving your specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void getAppInstallTime(){
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        try {
           PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.example.sample", 0);
            Field field = PackageInfo.class.getField("firstInstallTime");
            long timestamp = field.getLong(info);
            Date date = new Date(timestamp);
            Log.e("DATE", date + "InMillies "+timestamp);
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.example.sample", 0);
   String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
   long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();
   Date dateMod = new Date(installed);
   Log.e("Updates","Updated Time"+dateMod+"  time in millies"+installed);
       } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SecurityException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't wannt to have the date of an app but the date of the android OS, when it got a update the last time.